# How to apply animation on dynamic created table layout?

Tags: android, scroll, tablelayout

I want to apply a couple of animation effects, like adding the rows on scroll up and deleting the rows on scroll down in a TableLayout.

How can I implement that?

Comment: i found example for list view  link :https://play.google.com/stor/apps/details?id=com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample but i want in table layout

Answer (score 0):

I've found an implementation of Jazzy List View

https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView

Comment: I want same effect in tablelayout